# difficulties with cx_freeze setup for kivy with Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, cx-freeze

I am trying to build a package for just a simple Python 2.7 + kivy 1.9.1 script using cx_freeze. Unfortunately I get the following error when executing the DoScroll.exe file:

*File "C:\Utils\Pyhton27\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1829, in load_file
with open(filename, 'r') as fd:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Projects\Testing\build\exe.win32-2.7\library.zip\kivy\data\style.kv'*

The zip file does not contain the kivy\data folder. So my idea was to add the kivy package explicitly to the setup.py file. But this does not help. 
How could I resolve this issue?

The setup.py file I am using:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'packages': ['kivy']
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('DoScroll.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='scroller',
      version='0.1',
      description='demo scroller',
      executables = executables,
      options=options
    )
```

Comment: why not pyinstaller which is also documented in docs?

Comment: Because I am running into errors when trying to install pyinstaller. Both when using pip and: python setup.py install.
  File "C:\Utils\Pyhton27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 39, in <module>
    winerror.DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND'

Comment: Badly installed `win32com`/crippled python?

Comment: You are right. Have removed everything and installed a fresh environment. Now pyinstaller works fine, but the generated dist package not. I will post a new question for this.

Comment: Relating question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36353830/5708480?sem=2