# kivy fatal error due to OpenGL requirement on windows desktop

Tags: windows, python-2.7, opengl, kivy

I have written a windows desktop application using  Python 2.7 and kivy that runs perfectly well from the pyCharm IDE and from the python commandline. After building a distribution package using PyInstaller, running the application from the ..\dist\applicdir\ I get a Kivy Fatal Error:

*GL:Minimum required OpenGL version (2.0) NOT found!*

How come? It runs from 2 different angles on the same PC but not from the dist package on the same PC.

Can you explain to me why in the first two situations I do not get the fatal Error?

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>> EDIT 1 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in ~\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-04-01_99.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015,20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[WARNING           ] The 'fake' fullscreen option has been deprecated, use Window.borderless or the borderless Config option instead.
[INFO              ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.4176>

[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 0
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Shading version <4.00 - Build 10.18.10.4176>

[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO              ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
LOADER: executable is C:\Projects\UP52\PACKAGE\dist\up52creator\up52creator.exe
LOADER: homepath is C:\Projects\UP52\PACKAGE\dist\up52creator
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
LOADER: archivename is C:\Projects\UP52\PACKAGE\dist\up52creator\up52creator.exe

LOADER: No need to extract files to run; setting extractionpath to homepath
LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Projects\UP52\PACKAGE\dist\up52creator)
LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
LOADER: Python library: C:\Projects\UP52\PACKAGE\dist\up52creator\python27.dll
LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Projects\UP52\PACKAGE\dist\UP52CR~1
LOADER: Setting runtime options
LOADER: Initializing python
LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Projects\UP52\PACKAGE\dist\up52creator
LOADER: Setting sys.argv
LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
LOADER: extracted struct
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
LOADER: PYZ archive: out00-PYZ.pyz
LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
no mem to add parser accelerators
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
   File "C:\Projects\UP52\qmonos.py", line 56, in showHome
     recMgr = Manager()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 99, in Manager
     m.start()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 528, in start
     self._address = reader.recv()
 EOFError
qmonosmain returned -1
LOADER: OK.
LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
   File "C:\Projects\UP52\qmonos.py", line 56, in showHome
     recMgr = Manager()
   File "C:\Projects\UP52\qmonos.py", line 56, in showHome
   File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 99, in Manager
     m.start()
     recMgr = Manager()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 528, in start
   File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 99, in Manager
      m.start()
    self._address = reader.recv()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 528, in start
 EOFError
qmonosmain returned -1
LOADER: OK.
LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
     self._address = reader.recv()
 EOFError
qmonosmain returned -1
LOADER: OK.
LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
```

Comment: Error like [this one](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3576)?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the graphics drivers and the problem is gone. But still not able to get my application running after PyInstaller package creation. Now the 'kivy' screen turns black...

Comment: Try  touchtracer and if it works, something is wrong with your code. And some debug(enable with `--debug` in pyinstaller) log would be nice.

Comment: I tested a simple own developed kivy application which works fine. The application of concern makes use of multiprocessing. And looking at some posts this gives problems whit PyInstaller. The application runs into an endless loop spawning processes and black windows and eating memory till the machine blocks completely.

Comment: I have added some logging info above. See ">>>>>> EDIT 1 <<<<<<<<<"

Comment: Followed the recipe at: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Multiprocessing. Unfortunately this does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the graphics driver solved the problem. But still a strange situation that after PyInstaller package creation the application triggers on OpenGL version issues and the PyCharm IDE and Python commandline do not.......