# How to solve the error "Try upgrading your graphics drivers and/or your graphics hardware in case of problems" using kivy pyinstaller In windows 8?

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I am creating a windows application using the kivy framework. It works fine while i run the application using python cmd.

If i create a executable file using pyinstaller it is showing error as Try upgrading your graphics drivers and/or your graphics hardware in case of problems

**Sample Code :**

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')

import os
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'
```

**Spec file :**

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['woocommerse_remote.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\ttttt\\Desktop\\'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz, Tree('C:\\Users\\tttt\\Desktop\\'),
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          [],
          name='woocommerse_remote',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

**Error Screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: Similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353830/kivy-fatal-error-due-to-opengl-requirement-on-windows-desktop) was solved by upgrading the graphics driver. Have you tried that?

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thanks for reply , That problem solved after i installed cpython. Another error occurs after creating exe file **unable to get a window , about**. i have also included the sdl2 on the spec. Please find the above spec file